# quote mark (U+0027) in perl substitution

Tags: regex, zsh, perl

I need to put two spaces between sentences in a large number of text files.

A sentence ending is defined as period, exclamation, or question, maybe a close-quote, and then a space.  Tabs and line breaks intentionally omitted.

So, this does most of the work:

```
perl -p -i -e 's:([.?!]["”’»]?) :\1  :g;' *txt
```

What's missing is that sometimes a single-quote might be there instead of a double.  I have the "curly" version (U+2019) in there, but if I include the ASCII version, the shell wants me to finish the job with another (fourth) one.  If I escape the quote/apostrophe (backslash), no change.  Two backslashes, no change.  Even tried three.

If I take the double quote out (or escape it, and put double instead of single outside the script, I get `-bash: !][\'\: event not found`

Problem exists with bash in Debian and zsh in MacOS.

**How can we make an apostrophe (U+0027) be accepted in a regex?**

Comment: See the last two sentences: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html Consider: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html

Comment: Or maybe: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html

Comment: Since it's UTF-8, x27 worked instead of u0027.  But it also sounds like I could put `sh` on the bang line (which actually runs bash on my system) to force POSIX mode, and then the double-quote version would work.  Maybe you could flesh all that out as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (Linux, but perl is perl ..., same for bash)

```
perl -i -p -e 's:([.?!]["”’\x27»]?) :\1  :g;' *txt
```

Especially because you overwrite the original files and may sometimes not know if you already did it: If you need exactly 2 spaces between sentences, use this instead (including negative lookahead for already existing 2nd space):

```
perl -i -p -e 's:([.?!]["”’\x27»]?) (?! ):\1  :g;' *txt
```